# Oracle range query

Tags: sql

I've found this query on this site (slightly modified it though) and it works OK. However,the result set doesn't show the range intervals where count(*) is 0. I tried to use the NVL function along with left joint, but couldn't make it work. Any ideas? (see query below)

Thanks

```
select
    count(*) "# PRs Created",to_char(date_created, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as "Date Created",
    to_char(date_created, 'hh24') || ':00:00 - ' || to_char(date_created + 1/24, 'hh24') || ':00:00' RANGE 
    FROM pr
    where date_created between to_date(SYSDATE - 1000)and to_date(SYSDATE)
    and 1 * to_char(date_created, 'hh24') between 0 and 24
    group by to_char(date_created, 'hh24'), to_char(date_created + 1/24, 'hh24'),to_char(date_created, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    order by to_char(date_created, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), RANGE  desc
```

Comment: Create structures and post desired output. RANGE maybe a keyword as in Oracle SQL for example. I would not use such aliases...

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a zero entry for non-existent intervals because there's nothing to count. To get this to work, you'll need to outer join to a table of date times:

```
with dates as (
  select trunc(sysdate)-1000 + (rownum-1)/24 dt
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 1000 * 24
)
select dates.dt, count(pr.date_created) from pr, dates
where  trunc(pr.date_created (+), 'hh24')= dates.dt
group  by dates.dt;
```

The `with` clause creates a "table" of data containing every hour from `sysdate-1000` and today (the condition in your query). You need to outer join `pr` to this to see a row for intervals that have no entry in `pr`.